# MrSid => GeoTiff

Tags: raster, convert, geotiff-tiff, mac, mrsid

I have a MrSid file that I would like to convert to a GeoTiff. Is there a way to do this on a Mac running Mountain Lion? I know it can be done on Windows and Linux using the LizardTech command line utilities.

Comment: Do you have GDAL/OGR? That would probably be the easiest way. See (for example) http://www.kyngchaos.com/macosx/build/gdal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use gdal_translate.

Here are some instructions on its use:
http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

Here is the download page including some information about setting it up in Mountain Lion:
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries
http://www.kyngchaos.com/software:frameworks

If you want to build it yourself:
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnMac

Depending on the binary you may have to extend it to implement MrSID functionality or it may already be in. I don't have Mountain Lion and can't say for sure.

Alternatively the same website includes other GIS software including Quantum GIS you might want to check out.

Comment: I ended up just using a GDAL library for windows that included the MrSid plugin. The fact that MrSid is not turned on by default lead me to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it!